# Specifying item list contents in Entity Framework with two conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Most often we find a generic list with code like:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID);
Item.Quantity = Quantity;
Item.Price = Price;
```

So the above code finds and updates with another data, but if I want to find by multiple condition then how do I write the code?

I want to write code like:

```
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID
                              and c.ProductName IN ("cake,bread,toast,drink"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Create a array/list of string of dynamic search keyword and check against it as below:

```
var conditionarr = new []{"cake","bread","toast","drink"}; // your array or list of string
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID 
 && conditionarr.Contains(c.ProductName));
```

Comment: What if you have a `List<long>`? I have an error in convertion.

Comment: Contains works with any collection string, int, long... I believe you do not need any conversion. e.g. List<long> l, then you should use l.Contains(c.ProductId)

Comment: Actually I got it now. I cast the `c.ProductID` to `(long)` like `(long)c.ProductID` inside the `Contains()` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your query will look like this:

```
var serachIn="cake,bread,toast,drink";

CartItem Item = Items.Where(c => c.ProductID == ProductID &&
                            serachIn.Contains(c.ProductName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>{ "cake", "bread", "toast", "drink" };
CartItem Item = Items.Find(c => c.ProductID == ProductID && strList.Contains(c.ProductName))
```